# jQuery Change Function'Unexpected Token ILLEGAL'

Tags: jquery, buddypress

Been a while:

I am trying to use a jQuery function to change / or add data into an Input Field Form but I get the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

My Function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(‘input#signup_username’).change(function () {
            $(‘input#field_1′).val($(this).val());
        });
    })
</script>
```

I am trying to follow [advice on a buddyPress Forum here](http://buddypress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-xprofile-names-and-replace-with-username/) to hide and change xProfile data on a BuddyPress registration form.

The suggestion:

> - On the registration form hide the xProfile name field (CSS display: none) and make a javascript listener (CHANGE) function to change the
>     xProfile name field to the value of the WP username. This will take
>     care of the form validation – xProfile name field is required. See
>     reference…
>
>   Reference: jQuery(‘input#signup_username’).change(function () {
>     jQuery(‘input#field_1′).val(jQuery(this).val()); });

No one has replied saying that it works or not but my fist obstacle is this token error.

So, any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I noticed you have Microsoft "Curly" quotes. Are those in your code, or did you copy and paste from something? (I would estimate that curly quotes have wasted nearly 40 hours of my time throughout my career)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't normal single quotes. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input#signup_username').change(function () {
        $('input#field_1').val($(this).val());
    });
})
```

Comment: OMG!  I am such a bone-head (Too tired too)! I need to stop copying and pasting.. LOL  Thnx for catching that.